# How to write tests for active record scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

How can I write tests for active record scopes? for example

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, -> { order("posts.created_at DESC") }
  scope :published, -> { where("status = 1") }
end
```

I'm using Rspec for testing

```
RSpec.feature Post, :type => :model do
  let(:post) { build(:post) }

  describe 'test scopes' do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you have the appropriate fixtures setup, I usually run a query where I expect results from the scope, and one where I don't. For example:

```
describe '#published' do
  it "returns a published post" do
    expect(Post.published.count).to be(1)
    # or inspect to see if it's published, but that's a bit redundant
  end

  it "does not return unpublished posts" do
    expect(Post.published).to_not include(Post.where("status = 0"))
  end
end
```